# Python delete character in a string

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm stuck, I've searched several ways and I can't get the correct output.

```
string = "Hello! I have a Big!!! problem 666 is not a good number__$"
ns =''.join([i for i in string if i.isalpha()])
print(ns)
```

HelloIhaveaBigproblemisnotagoodnumber

I want this output:

Hello I have a Big problem is not a good number

Can you help me? Thank you!!

Comment: But there, you just described what you don't want. You didn't say what you want. I mean, which criteria leads to "Hello I have a Big problem is not a good number". To you want to remove digits and punctuation? Or to remove everything but letters and spaces?

Comment: thanks for ask, I want to remove the non-alphabetic characters, but I want to get the string as a sentence separated word by word

Comment: In general for example if i have an string with ()/#@€

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could increase the conditions used for each character, e.g.,

```
ns =''.join([i for i in string if i == " " or i.isalpha()])
```

But there is a problem with sequences like "666 " that leave an extra space in the text.

Instead, you could use a regex to break the string down into a list of words and intervening non-word text. Filter out the stuff you don't want, and then remove any items where the word itself went to zero size.

```
import re

string = "Hello! I have a Big!!! problem 666 is not a good number__$"
tmp = []

for word, other in re.findall(r"(\w+)([^\w]*)", string):
    # strip non-alpha
    word = "".join(c for c in word if c.isalpha())
    # preserve only spaces
    other = "".join(c for c in other if c == " ")
    # only add if word still exists
    if word:
        tmp.append(word + other)
ns = "".join(tmp)
print(ns)
```

Output

```
Hello I have a Big problem is not a good number
```

Comment: Pure pythonic!! +1 from my side

Answer (score 2):

Filter uisng `re` & remove them using `re.sub`

```
import re
string = "Hello! I have a Big!!! problem 666 is not a good number__$"
print (re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+', ' ', string))
```

output #

```
Hello I have a Big problem is not a good number
```

Comment: With a warning: It doesn't work for non-English alphabets.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of simple problems can be solved without the `re` library.

For this case, you can `filter` all characters that are not in the alphabet, or empty spaces:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
ns = ''.join(filter(lambda c: c.lower() in ascii_lowercase+' ', s))
while '  ' in ns: ns = ns.replace('  ',' ')


# output:
# 'Hello I have a Big problem is not a good number'
```

Repeated spaces are filtered in the one-liner `while-loop` found above.

---

To work with non-english characters, you can replace `ascii_lowercase` with the desired choice of characters.

Comment: But then you have 2 spaces between `problem` and `is`

Comment: The updated version also solves this problem.

Comment: Thanks to all, I can continue with the learning of python, greetings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import re

string = "Hello! I have a Big!!! problem 666 is not a good number__$"
regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z ]')
print(regex.sub('', string))
```

And it will print:

**Hello I have a Big problem  is not a good number**

(With double space between "problem" and "is")

If you want to remove the double space you write it like this:

```
import re

string = "Hello! I have a Big!!! problem 666 is not a good number__$"
regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z ]')
string = regex.sub('', string)
print(string.replace('  ', ' '))
```

And now the output will be:

**Hello I have a Big problem is not a good number**